# Yarn install | warning Pattern is trying to unpack in the same destination

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am new to Yarn the package manager.  I am getting below error. Could someone help me?

```
 D:\test\0x-starter-project-master>yarn install
 yarn install v1.12.1
 [1/4] Resolving packages...
 [2/4] Fetching packages...
 warning Pattern ["ethereumjs-abi@git+https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v3\\npm-ethereumjs-abi-0.6.5-4ea2fdfed09e8f99117d9362d17c6b01b64a2bcf\\node_modules\\ethereumjs-abi" as pattern ["ethereumjs-abi@0.6.5","ethereumjs-abi@^0.6.5","ethereumjs-abi@0.6.5"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
 [---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/884
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems `yarn` can have problems figuring out dependencies sometimes.
A workaround in this case is:

1. Run `yarn why <problem_package_name_here>` to find all of the dependencies on that package.  In your case, that would be `yarn why ethereumjs-abi` - keep a note of all of these dependent packages.
2. Then `yarn remove` that package and all packages that are dependent on it.
3. `yarn add <problem_package_name_here>` first (i.e. `yarn add ethereumjs-abi` in your case).
4. And finally, `yarn add <all> <the> <other> <packages> <you> <removed> <in> <step 2>`

Now `yarn` should no longer be confused about dependencies etc.

Comment: it worked the first time for me.. then I got the error again

Answer (score -4):

I was experiencing a similar error using yarn to install the gulp-cli.
This work-around solution worked for me: 
Use npm to install the module that yarn would not install.